# Ubuntu drops me a GRUB prompt, no wubildr

Tags: startup

I try to start Ubuntu since yesterday and he doesn't want to start.
The first screen said:

```
try (hd0,0): NTFS5 : no wubildr           
try (hd0,1): NTFS5: error: ''prefix'' is not set.
```

And it switches to:

```
GNU GRUB   version 1.99-21ubuntu3.4
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB list possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>
```

What I should do?

Answer (score 0):

reinstall Ubuntu would be the easiest way to go I think.

Check this link:

[WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)